# How to get lines after the word match and before other specific word?

Tags: regex

I have this string:

> Overview
>
> Somebody request a review
>
> Title
>
> Test
>
> Test
>
> Resolution

I would like get all the lines after the word "**Overview**" and before the Word "**Resolution**"

I tried this Regex: `Overview.*[\r\n]+(.*)`

https://regex101.com/r/QibhMq/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might seem like an overkill, but nested repeating group and the actual boundary words should be pretty robust:

```
Overview[\r\n]((?:.*[\r\n].*)*)Resolution
```

Demo in JS:

```js
const data = `Something
Overview
Somebody request a review
Title
Test
Test
Resolution
Blah
Something`

const after = "Overview"
const before = "Resolution"

const regex = new RegExp(`${after}[\r\n]((?:.*[\r\n].*)*)${before}`)

const match = data.match(regex)
if (match) console.log(match[1])
```

[image]

Demo and explanation on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/QibhMq/6

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I needed. Appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use the modifiers. I would recommend the use of

**/s** **singleline**

```
Overview.*[\r\n]+(.*)/s
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QibhMq/2)**

Comment: Edit: Looks like it gives all the all lines Overview. but put resolution in the group 1. I just need Somebody to Test then exclude resolution from the string.

Comment: I mean I just need the text between Overview and Resolution